# In Typescript, how to copy an object of a specific type to an other object of a different but similar type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to copy an object of a specific type, to another object of an other type but similar type.

Givin this example:

```
interface PersonInfo {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  length: number
}

interface Person {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

I tried

```
const a: PersonInfo = {
  firstName: "john",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 23,
  length: 180
}

const b: Person = a
```

I want that `const b:Person = { firstName: "john", lastName: "Doe", }`

I don't know if this is relevant, but I am not looking for a solution where `interface PersonInfo` can extend `interface Person`

Comment: You have to essentially do it explicitly; the interface definition isn't available at runtime so nothing knows which keys are "extra".  See the answers to the linked question for more information.